# Symfony 3 Apache 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache2, symfony, internal-server-error

I'm using Symfony 3.2.3 and switched from PHP built-in Web Server to Apache (http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html, Apache 2.4.18). 
It works for the root Symfony page (http://example.com/, without Symfony routing), but when I'm creating a controller with a routing (e.g. @Route("/development", name="development")), I got an Apache 500 Internal Server Error. When requesting this side (/development) with PHP built-in Web Server, it works fine. In Apache log I do not get any error message. PHP "display_error" is on, "error_reporting" is "E_ALL" and there is no messsage in php "error_log" file.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: The 500 error is a generic error. Most likely there is some other problem, and potentially a twig issue. Can you use the DEV URL like so: `http://domain.com/app_dev.php`. Then you will be able to see what the error is.

Comment: If I use "http://domain.com/app_dev.php/development" it works without error. When calling "http://domain.com/app.php/development" i got redirected to "http://domain.com/development" and there is again the error 500.
I disabled this in apache config: 
"<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>". But has not changes anything. Is it possible to change from app.php as default to app_dev.php?

Comment: Can you check the contents of your logs? They are located in `var/logs` and there should be `dev.log` and `prod.log`. You can clear the files first, and then do your test until you get the 500 errors and then check those files. Also run `php bin/symfony_requirements` from the command line.

Comment: Those files (`prod.log` and `dev.log`) do not exist.I enabled custom log by apache: `ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_development_error.log, CustomLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_development_access.log`. In those files there is no error when calling the side, I only got error 500 in `symfony_development_access.log`.

Comment: Make sure you set the `var` folder [permissions correctly as per this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html). You definately will get the file `var/logs/dev.log` once you use the `http://domain.com/app_dev.php` URL.

Comment: `php bin/symfony_requirements`: `[OK] Your system is ready to run Symfony projects`.

Comment: Sorry I checked `/var/logs` in root directory. Yes I found those files, error is `No route found for "GET /development"`. But this route works fine with `app_dev.php`. Do I have to add the controllers separately for `app.php`? Controller is in `/src/AppBundle/Controller`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look like your problem is your cache hasn't been cleared in production. Run this command:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Then run:

```
php bin/console debug:router -e=prod
```

Which should show all your production routes. By the way running:

```
php bin/console
```

shows you all the commands you can run from the command line, if you need to look at anything else.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!

`php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

solved the issue! That's great!

How often do I have to clear the cache? Every time when I add new routes? Do I have to do this only for prod environment or also for dev?

Comment: Note: `php bin/console debug:router -e=prod` equals `php bin/console debug:router --env=prod`. You should click the arrow besides my answer to show it is correct.

Comment: Would be nice if you could answer my questions finally. Thank you very much! How often do I have to clear the cache? Every time when I add new routes? Do I have to do this only for prod environment or also for dev?

Comment: You only need to clear the `prod` cache everytime you make a change to your controllers or your twig files. The `dev` is done automatically. However, if you are having issues, it doesn't hurt to use the command.

Comment: `-e prod` or `--env=prod`