# Symfony 3.4, apache 2, ubuntu 16, php 7.2 - 500 error

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I tried to debug using die() in app.php and I see this line gets the error. Before this line script works.

```
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

Checked logs:

```
   tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

No data in it. Before checking I removed this file and created so it would be empty.

Virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName 178.62.70.115

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony_3_subscribers_in_file_demo/web

    <Directory "/var/www/symfony_3_subscribers_in_file_demo/web">
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to app_dev.php, then I get

> You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more
>   information.

I have cleared cache like said here:

[Symfony 3 Apache 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255167/symfony-3-apache-500-internal-server-error)

Where else to look for a problem? By the way on my development machine its the same - app.php also give 500 error. Only app_dev.php works.

**Update**

Answering to comment - are logs and cache dirs writable:

```
drwxrwxr-x 4 darius darius  4096 Jan  8 10:02 cache
drwxrwxr-x 2 darius darius  4096 Jan  8 10:02 logs
```

Since there is one minus in each, they are partly writable.

Comment: Are `var/logs`, `var/cache` etc directories writable?

Comment: @ArtOsi - partly yes. Maybe it is enough. Isn't symfony installation script not handling permissions?

Comment: in versions 3.x no, you have set permissions  `chmod 777 -R var/log/` or something

Answer (score 0):

As ArtOsi wrote - there were problems with writing.

After setting write permissions to 777 to cache, logs and sessions folders in var folder, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization is needed to access development environment in Symfony.

Open **web/app_dev.php** file and add your ip in trusted list.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1','27.131.14.9']) || PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

Trusted IPs are defined in an array in the code:

```
['127.0.0.1', '::1','27.131.14.9', 'YourTrustedIP']
```